# can roles be assigned to users and groups in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have recently started AWS certified developer from udemy. In the tutorial they state: "Roles CANNOT be assigned to Users or Groups like Policies can ". But my search on the internet says Roles can be assigned to users and groups in AWS.

Could someone please untangle my confusion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Role is a group of policies tied together and linked to a specific entity (AWS service, AWS account or web identities) **and not for IAM User or Group**.
IAM User/Group is sort of a role if you think about it, because it has a list of policies attached to it that a developer logged in with the specified credentials may use.
Also, if you try to play with the AWS Console a little you'll find that you cannot attach Roles to Users and Groups, only Policies.

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer: No!

---

You have got your definitions of those terms a bit confused:

- **IAM User** = Single Account with credentials for login, e.g. JohnDoe
- **IAM Role** = Single Account without credentials, created for AWS Resources to "Assume", e.g. MyWebServerRole could be used by EC2 instances running web services
- **IAM Group** = A collection of IAM Users, e.g. WebAdmins could have special permissions for the group, and IAM Users can be added or removed as needed, like an AD Group.
- **IAM Policy** = Resource Access Rules, e.g. List EC2 Instances.

**Policies are added to Users, Roles, or Groups, to give them the permissions specified in the policy.**

---

If you are studying for your Associate Exams, you should also be reading the [AWS FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/faqs/), and [AWS White Papers](https://aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/). They are some of the best material available to prepare you for the exam.

The [IAM FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/) is quite clear to read in answering these kind of questions:

> **Q: What is a group?**
>   A group is a collection of IAM users. Manage group membership as a simple list:
>   Add users to or remove them from a group.
>   A user can belong to multiple groups.
>   Groups cannot belong to other groups.
>   Groups can be granted permissions using access control policies. This makes it easier to manage permissions for a collection of users, rather than having to manage permissions for each individual user.
>   Groups do not have security credentials, and cannot access web services directly; they exist solely to make it easier to manage user permissions. For details, see Working with Groups and Users.
>
> **Q: What is an IAM role?**
>   An IAM role is an IAM entity that defines a set of permissions for making AWS service requests. IAM roles are not associated with a specific user or group. Instead, trusted entities assume roles, such as IAM users, applications, or AWS services such as EC2.
>
> **Q: What is the difference between an IAM role and an IAM user?**
>   An IAM user has permanent long-term credentials and is used to directly interact with AWS services. An IAM role does not have any credentials and cannot make direct requests to AWS services. IAM roles are meant to be assumed by authorized entities, such as IAM users, applications, or an AWS service such as EC2.
>
> **Q: How do permissions work?** 
>   Access control policies are attached to users, groups, and roles to assign permissions to AWS resources. By default, IAM users, groups, and roles have no permissions; users with sufficient permissions must use a policy to grant the desired permissions.
>
> **Q: How do I assign permissions using a policy?** 
>   To set permissions, you can create and attach policies using the AWS Management Console, the IAM API, or the AWS CLI. Users who have been granted the necessary permissions can create policies and assign them to IAM users, groups, and roles.

Comment: Does it mean that udemy explanation is misleading ?